# how to identify which version of angular (1,2 or 4) is used?

Tags: angularjs, angular

#### How to indentify angular version from angular js source file

I have found different source file version at https://code.angularjs.org/
like 1.6.X ,1.5.x, 1.4.x, 1.3.x and 1.2.x but how to identify which version of angular (1,2 or 4) is used ?

Thanks & Regards
Mithlesh Singh

Comment: `angular.js` file will have version mentioned in it.

Comment: i have checked all comments in source file so all js file is part of angular 1 ? so where can i find angular 2 or 4 source file ?

Comment: You will get the files through angular cli

Comment: The Angular 2,4,and 5 source is written in TypeScript. The GitHub is https://github.com/angular/angular ; The AngularJS 1.X source is written in JavaScript. The GitHub is https://github.com/angular/angular.js

Answer (score 10):

Open your browser's console (F12), go to Console Tab and type:

`angular.version.full`

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking at the source file, the angular version is at the top of `angular.js` in a comment. Example:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/angular.js

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.5.11
 * (c) 2010-2017 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
```